# Difference Between GUI debugger and terminal debuggers

Tags: c++, debugging

What are some advantages to a GUI debugger like in Eclipse and what are some advantages to using a command line debugger such as gdb? Does industry use command line debuggers? and if so, what situations do people use command line debuggers?

Comment: You can have front ends for terminal debuggers (which have their use, see answers). The converse is not true. My personal taste when using gdb is to use the command line (or the emacs front end sometimes), since you quickly get used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use gdb, but some advantages I can think of off the top of my head:

- Being command line, debugging binaries on remote systems is as easy as opening an ssh connection.
- Great scripting support, and the ability to run many commands per breakpoint (See the `continue` keyword)
- Much shorter start-up time and a faster development cycle.
- Copy&pastable commands and definable functions that let you repeat common commands easier
- gdb also speaks a well-defined protocol, so you can debug code running on lots of obscure hardware and kernels.
- Typing short commands is shorter and more efficient in the long run than working around a GUI (in my opinion).

However, if you're next to a system or runtime you've never used before, using a visual debugger can be easier to get started from the get-go. Also, having your debugger be tightly integrated with your IDE (if you use one) can be a big boost in productivity.

Visual debugger and command line ones don't have to be completely separate, there are visual front ends for gdb, such as DDD. (I don't use DDD however since it feels ultra kludgy and outdated. It does exist though. XCode also wraps gdb for debugging support)

Answer (score 2):

Command line debugger is good for debugging a remote system (especially when the connection is slow), it is also useful for low performance systems or systems without Xserver/graphic card. CLI debuggers are also used for quick analysis or core dump and SIGSEGVs (they are faster to start). Command-line debuggers are more portable, they are installed almost on every system (or them can be easily installed, or even started from network/flash drive)

I think that command-line can be used for programs without source, and the graphical debuggers are better for projects with complex data structures/classes.

Another situation is that command-line debuggers easier to automatize, e.g. I have a shell script, which do a full call graph logging of program using gdb. It will be very hard to automate a graphic debugger.

Comment: You mentioned that command-line does not require sources. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @foboi1122, they can work even if there are no sources of the program. Many graphical debuggers can work too in such situation, but I prefer to use CLI debuggers for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially impossible to compare meaningfully based on the debugger's display. People who like command lines are likely to use text mode, command-driven debuggers. People who like GUIs are likely to use graphical, menu-driven debuggers.

Nearly the only time there's a really strong technical motivation toward one or the other is if you're debugging a windowing system. For example, using a debugger that depends on a having a functional X Server doesn't work very well if what you're trying to debug *is* the X Server itself.